How can I reduce calculate to draw graphic of the problem 2004 AMC 12A Problems/Problem 22
I am trying to draw 2004 AMC 12A Problems/Problem 22
Three mutually tangent spheres of radius $1$ rest on a horizontal plane. A sphere of radius $2$ rests on them. What is the distance from the plane to the top of the larger sphere?
This is an answer with TikZ


And this is my code
sph1 = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
sph2 = Ball[{0, 2, 0}, 1];
sph3 = Ball[{1, Sqrt[3], 0}, 1];
sph4 = Ball[{1/3, (2 + Sqrt[3])/3, Sqrt[69]/3}, 2];
Graphics3D[{sph1, sph2, sph3, sph4}, Boxed -> False]

One angle of view

It is not a nice view.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

r1 = 1; r2 = 2;

balls = Ball[#, r1] & /@
   (2/Sqrt[3]*({#[[1]], #[[2]], 0} & /@ CirclePoints[3]));

eqns = And @@ (RegionDistance[#, {x, y, z}] == r2 & /@ balls);

ctr4 = SolveValues[eqns && z > 0, {x, y, z}, Reals][[1]]

(* {0, 0, Sqrt[23/3]} *)

Graphics3D[{
  Transpose@{{Red, Blue, Orange}, balls},
  {Green, Ball[ctr4, 2]}},
 Axes -> True]


dist = r1 + ctr4[[3]] + r2

(* 3 + Sqrt[23/3] *)

dist // N

(* 5.76887 *)

